# IndexError when trying to print 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to print the elements of a 2D array:

```
import numpy as np
sessional=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
for i in sessional:
        print (sessional[i])
```

However, it results in the following error:

```
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

I would like to see the following output:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're passing the actual elements of the `sessional` array as an index to itself. If you want to print each element of the array, you should replace `print (sessional[i])` with `print (i)`:

```
import numpy as np
sessional = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
for i in sessional:
        print (i)
```

Output:

```
[1 2]
[3 4]
[5 6]
```

If you really want the format you specified, you can use string formatting in your print statement:

```
import numpy as np
sessional = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
for i in sessional:
        print ("[{0},{1}]".format(i[0], i[1]))
```

Output:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
```